Why ею here rather than её?
I'm a bit confused by this sentence from the Russian translation of the book Atomic Habits:

Он с трудом сдерживал слезы, когда объяснял сестре, что в тот вечер
не сможет присутствовать на торжестве, посвященном окончанию
ею восьмого класса.

I would have naively expected to see её here, an invariant third-person possessive, and initially thought it was a typo. But as far as I can tell the audiobook disagrees with me and says ею too. What's going on here grammatically?

This clause uses passive voice: "...celebration of the completion by her of the 8th grade". "ею" is the instrumental form of the pronoun "она".

Ah, I see, thank you! Could you also express this as "...её окончанию восьмого класса", "her completion of the eighth grade", or is this always done with an instrumental rather than a possessive?

nope that won't work
